# Сдвиг элемента ListView

Tags: android, listview

Собственно, нужно реализовать фишку как в самсунговском тач визе.

Имеется список контактов - ListView. Нужно сделать так, чтобы при сдвиге элемента влево начинался вызов контакта.

Список уже заполнен, вызов как сделать знаю. Нужна конкретно реализация сдвига.

Заранее спасибо всем за ответы!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Определяете [Gesture](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/package-summary.html) - жест
2. Определяете действие по созданной Gesture через `OnGesturePerformedListener()` - в вашем случае вызов номера, там же рисуете некую анимацию жеста

Comment: Спасибо!
Почитал статью о жестах на хабре, в целом все понятно. Единственное, что я пока не пойму - как я буду определять, на каком именно из элементов списка выполнен жест?

Comment: кастомный адаптер

Comment: @Gorets слабо реализовать в нашей аппе?

Comment: Т.е. я делаю адаптер, который использует xml файл для пунктов списка. В этом xml файле вставляю стой отслеживания жестов, а в адаптере, при создании списка, задаю действие при использовании жеста на пункте списка?

Comment: @Grafity, сделаешь - кинь код =) я начинал и не осилил, будут проблемы так как жесты забирают на себя лонгПресс и онКлик листенеры (надо их делать на основе жестов)

Comment: @Grafity я знаю только в теории как это делается - как то читал статейку в каком-то блоге. Крайне любопытно будет увидеть реализацию вживую этой фичи

Comment: Да я пока понятия и не имею, как делать то. Что-то я застрял совсем.

Сейчас у меня простой адаптер на основе BaseAdapter, который формирует ListView из кусков item.xml, в котором наложен слой для жестов. 
Как узнать на каком из элементов сделан жест? В адаптере какую-то функцию добавить?
Мне нужно из текстового поля списка забрать телефон и позвонить на него. В случае с простым адаптером я просто в OnItemClickListener вытаскивал телефон и звонил на него.
Я первый раз писал свой адаптер, и то, по примеру из интернета.

Обычные нажатия мне не нужны, нужен только сдвиг. Хоть в этом мне повезло.

Comment: ну почти правильно, в своем адаптере, в месте где ты формируешь вьюху, на каждую добавляй Gesture листенер, ставь тег, а дальше разберешься, смотри другие примеры

Comment: Так этот OnGesturePerformedListener надо имплементировать активности, как сказано в статье на хабре. А мне к кому присобачить его?
К View, которая там есть предлагает только простые тач листенеры.